# How to store how many times did boolean return false/true

Tags: java, boolean, storing-data

I am trying to make a hangman game using boolean res to detect if the user input letter was equal to word at index i and if it is not res will remain false. when i type in a letter thats inside my word, it returns true on the correct letter and false on the rest.

my plan is to minus 1 life. only if the number of false returned is equal to the length of the word, but i do not know how to store the number of false(s) returned in order to compare it to the length of the word

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class res{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word ="Hello";
        int guessedLetters = 0;

        //System.out.print(" Word has "+word.length()+" letters ");
        //System.out.print("    You have 9 lives left     ");

        while(guessedLetters<word.length()) {

            int lives = 9;
            char input = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
            lives =livesLeft(lives, word, input, guessedLetters);
            //res = resolved(res, word, input, lives);

            //Lives
            //method to guess
            //initial word
            //what to do if letter is not correct
            //what to do if letter is correct

        }

    }


    public static int livesLeft( int lives, String word, char input, int guessedLetters) {

        boolean res = false;

        for(int i =0; i<word.length();i++) {

            if(input==word.charAt(i)) {

                //System.out.print(" Your guessed the " + i + "th letter right");
                res = true;
                guessedLetters++;

            }else {

                res =false;
                lives--;

            }

            System.out.print(res+"  " + lives + "  ");

        }

        //if res returns false on word.length() many times lives --;

        //System.out.print(res+"  " + lives + "  ");

        //System.out.println("You have "+lives+" lives left ");
        //System.out.println("You have guessed "+guessedLetters
                    //+" out of " + word.length() +" letters in the word ");

        return lives;


    }

    public static void printGameState() {

        //method to print out How many letters guessed

    }

}
```

I expect it to print True and keep int lives at it's orginal value if user input is right and print false and minus 1 from int lives if user input is wrong. Actual input is just number of lives stuck at 9

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you right. But you have a variable 'lives' which is equal 9. The Problem here is you have your 'lives' initialized inside your while loop. That means after every guess lives will be again 9. To fix this, you should probably initialize your variable before the loop (Line 9-15):

```
int guessedLetters = 0;
int lives = 9;

while(guessedLetters<lives) {
  ...
}
```

There will also be a Problem with counting down the lives.
In the method 'livesLeft' you have a for loop, which iterates through every letter of the word. And right now you subtract one after if the letter is not correct.

```
for(int i =0; i<word.length();i++) {
   ...
   if{
      ...
   }else {
      res =false;
      lives--; // <--- right here
   } 
}
```

For example, the word is 'Hello" and the player guessed the letter "A". The game will iterate through every letter by one. In the end you will lose 5 lives. I think this is not what you want. To solve this Problem you should subtract after the for loop like this:

```
for(int i =0; i<word.length();i++) {
   ...
}
lives--;
```

I hope this is a bit helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is setting `lives=9` so even if your method changes the value of `lives` the next time the loop comes around the value of lives is being reset to 9. Move your declaration and assigned of `lives` to outside your while loop